# object Object в теге option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я пытаюсь получит множество тегов `option` , component Addreess возвращает r`eturn adrress.features.find(place => place.id.match(region)).text,` если выведу в тег `<p></p>` без `select` получу мои данные, но в `options object Object`. Why?

```
<select name="cities" id="cities">
          {data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((edge) => {
            return (
              <Adrress x={edge.node.location.lon} y={edge.node.location.lat} />
            )
          }
          )}
     </select>
Output : <select name="cities" id="cities">WarsawManchester</select>
```

Меняю на

```
<option value=""><Adrress x={edge.node.location.lon} y={edge.node.location.lat} /></option>
Output :

<select name="cities" id="cities">
  <option value="">[object Object]</option>
  <option value="">[object Object]</option>
</select>
```

Comment: a Adrress что такое?

Comment: Компонент, который ретурнить строку

Comment: он ваш или из библиотеки какой?

Comment: Написаный мной, принимает координаты и возвращает название города, но не суть, в реакте 16.4 все нормально работает, а у меня 16.8 версия и тут ошибка

Comment: а если он перед возвращением обернет строку в тэг какой-нибудь

Comment: покажите код ретурн-а Adrress

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov в описании есть, я делал и через `${}` и toStrigify ... все варианты - результат один, в теге p, div ... все выводится

Comment: return **из** Adrress

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov  return adrress.features.find(place => place.id.match(region)).text

Comment: 1) в этом return-е в тэг оборачивать пробовали? 2) а features это что? проверьте что `.text` это текст

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov у меня компонент не только сюда идет, я же написал, что в тегах P, DIV, SPAN ... Все отрабатывает и в реакте 16.4 версии и ниже отрабатывает даже в option, ретурнится строка, я ее в стросчную даже оборачивал...

Comment: `return <span>adrress.features.find` что будет?

Comment: я знаю, что в option span-ов не бывает; но попробовать можно

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov решил npm react-select , если интересно, проще работать